# React.JS React-Router-Dom applying css on every routes

Tags: reactjs

i'm a beginner in react.js and i recently discovered react-router-dom but i have an issue with it if i apply css to my file all the other routes have this css how could i fix that issue?
My Code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGg7g.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0eOm.png

I guess it's because it import this page on every page but i have no idea how to fix the problem

Comment: Please post your code as (formatted) text, not as a linked image.

Answer (score 1):

You can import the css file inside your react component.

For example, you can import the `login.css` file in your `Login` component

**Edit:**

If you want to load the css files on demand, refer 
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

Comment: Ye that's what i do but it still adds the css into all routes this is login.jsx https://i.imgur.com/xUlmrib.png

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because of `react` bundle all things together.

You may need to set different `className` for your every page root parent div.

Also, Another way is to set a different `CSS/SCS` file in the corresponding `view Component.`

Like if I consider Login.jsx cmponent it return method would be like that:-

**For Login.jsx:-**

```
return(
  <div className="login-container">
   </div>
)
```

**For Registration.jsx:-**

```
return(
  <div className="registration-container">
   </div>
)
```